# Registrar cookie após pressionar botão

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Oi!

Estou tentando criar uma div pop up que mostrará o vídeo mais recente do meu canal do YouTube quando um usuário navegar pelo site, entretanto, existem algumas condições:

1. Ela deverá continuar aparecendo em outras páginas até que o usuário clique no botão de OK ou Sair. (Tipo um pop up de cookie que não desaparece até o Ok)
2. Ela deverá aparecer para o usuário novamente em alguns dias.

O código que encontrei na internet resolveu o ponto 2 da minha condição e está funcionando bem, entretanto, o ponto 1 ainda ficou em aberto.

Eu preciso disso pois existem algumas páginas que o pop up não aparecerá, e se o cookie for registrado sem a condição de clicar nos botões OK ou Sair, nas próximas páginas do fluxo de navegação do usuário a div não será exibida corretamente.

```
// Define cookie
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (encodeURIComponent(value) || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
};

// Obtêm cookie
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)===' '){ c = c.substring(1,c.length); }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0){ return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length)); }
    }
    return null;
};

// Apaga cookie
function eraseCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;'; 
};

// Exibe div uma única vez
function cspCheck(){

    // Obtêmos a div #custom-social-proof
    var csp = document.getElementById('alerta-card')

    // Escondemos a div #custom-social-proof ao chamar a função cspCheck()
    csp.style.display = "none";

    // Se tiver um cookie definido / se a div já foi exibida uma vez
    if(getCookie('csp')){

        // Escondemos a div
        csp.style.display = "none";

    // Se NÃO tiver um cookie definido / se a div nunca foi exibida
    } else {

        // Exibimos a div
        csp.style.display = "block";

        // Definimos um prazo em dias para o cookie ser deletado (para div voltar à aparecer)
        var cookiesExpireIn = 3; // dia(s)

        // Definimos o cookie indicando que a div já foi exibida uma vez
        setCookie('csp','1',cookiesExpireIn);

    }

}

// Chamamos a função ao carregar a página
window.onload = function() {
    cspCheck();
};
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bom primeiro você dever selecionar o button que fecha o pop up e adiciona um event de click nele e quando o usuário click você chame a function que set o cookie. Espero ter ajudado!!!

#### EXEMPLO

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.close-pop-up');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  alert('fechei pop up e set cookie')
  // chama a function que set o cookie ....
});
```

```css
.pop-up {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  background: #23212d;
}

.pop-up h1 {
   text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.pop-up button {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 6px 11px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #96f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop-up">
    
  <h1>Pop Up</h1>
  <button class="close-pop-up">
    fecha pop up
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!